# for (increase time delay) depending on object count

Tags: swift, math, time, formula

A math question. I am trying to animate objects sequentially, but I can't figure out formula which will allow me to set a delay smoothly. If I have, lets say, 2 object in my array I want them to animate almost normally with i*0.25 delay, but if I have 25 objects I want them to animate rather quickly. Yes I can try to set manual ratio switching the .count, but I think there should be a nice formula for this?

```
for (i,object) in objects.enumerated() {
    object.animate(withDelay: (i * 0.25) / objects.count)
}
```

Comment: So lets say 1st object's animation will be much faster than 10th object, but still you dont want it to be too long as number of objects increase right? In order to have a formula you need to have a clear purpose " I can't figure out formula which will allow me to set a delay smoothly" what kind of behaviour would be smooth for you? You need to answer that first.

Comment: you are saying about the duration, and i am asking about the delay before animation will start. let say the duration will be the same for all objects

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to choose an animation time that will happen EVERY time, no matter the # of variables.

```
let animateTime = 2 // 2 secs
let animateTimePerObject:Double = animateTime/objects.count
for (i,object) in objects.enumerated() {
    object.animate(withDelay: (i * animateTimePerObject) 
}
```

Say there are 10 objects, and you want to animate for 2 seconds. This will set `animateTimePerObject = 2/10 = .2` Each item will be delayed by `i (whatever position they are at) * the animatetime per object`. So in order, `0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2`.

Same could be done with 2 objects.

OR you could do a `log` function that would allow for growth but at a slower rate. Here are some [functions](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu//blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf) you could look at using.

Add this function to create a custom log functionality

```
func logC(val: Double, forBase base: Double) -> Double {
    return log(val)/log(base)
}

for (i,object) in objects.enumerated() {
    let delay = i == 0 ? .25 : logC(Double(i)*10, forBase: 10) * 0.25
    object.animate(withDelay: delay)
}

This will slow down your 0.25*i rate to a much slower one.

0 -> .25
1 -> Log(20, base: 10) = 1.3 * 0.25 = .325
...
25 -> Log(250, base: 10) = 2.3979 * 0.25 = .6
```

where it would have been

```
0 -> .25
1 -> .25 * 2 = .5
25 -> .25 * 25 = 6.25
```

You can play with the log function as you like, but these are just some ideas. It's not precise as to what kind of algorithm you are looking for.

**NOTE:** May be syntax issues in there slightly, with the `Double`s and `Int`s but you can adjust! :)

**Comparing Log and Sqrt:**

```
func logC(val: Double, forBase base: Double) -> Double {
    return log(val)/log(base)
}

for i in 0..<25 {
    let delay = i == 0 ? 0.25 : pow(logC(val: Double(i)*10, forBase: 10) * 0.25, log(1/Double(i))) * 0.45
    let delay2 = i == 0 ? 0.25 : sqrt(Double(i)) * 0.5
    print(delay, delay2)
}

0.25 0.25
0.45 0.5
0.9801911408397829 0.7071067811865476
1.3443747821649137 0.8660254037844386
1.5999258430124579 1.0
1.7853405889097305 1.118033988749895
1.9234257236285595 1.224744871391589
2.0282300761096543 1.3228756555322954
2.1088308307833894 1.4142135623730951
2.1713433790123178 1.5
2.2200343505615683 1.5811388300841898
2.2579686175608598 1.6583123951777
2.2874024254699274 1.7320508075688772
2.3100316733059247 1.8027756377319946
2.32715403828525 1.8708286933869707
2.33977794890637 1.9364916731037085
2.348697701417663 2.0
2.3545463958925756 2.0615528128088303
2.357833976756366 2.1213203435596424
2.358975047645847 2.179449471770337
2.35830952737025 2.23606797749979
2.3561182050020992 2.29128784747792
2.35263460234384 2.345207879911715
2.348054124507179 2.3979157616563596
2.3425411926260447 2.449489742783178
```

Comment: thanks. so far your log formula is better than nothing :)

Comment: Glad I could help! You can add coefficients to your log function and make it shorter or longer and it will increase/decrease at a log rate. I used logC(Double(i)*10, forBase:10) but you could change either of the 10s and play with the values. Also, if this is your currently accepted answer, don't forget to accept!

Comment: i already played with all values combining, mixing, dividing etc but still not perfect the last half is too close to each other, so i wait maybe someone will come up with better solution, if not - you'll get a credit :)

Comment: What about this `let delay = i == 0 ? 0.25 : pow(logC(val: Double(i)*10, forBase: 10) * 0.25, log(1/Double(i))) * 0.45`

Comment: this update just increased delay gap in the middle but the end half elements are still pretty close to each other(like 0.02 between)

Comment: Sorry buddy, wish I could be of more help. `Log` functions slow down incredibly fast and that is the point of them.

Comment: What about using square root vs log, square root dies out slower than log but has similar results. Try this and let me know. `let delay = i == 0 ? 0.25 : sqrt(Double(i)*4) * 0.25`

Comment: Or you might be interested in `let delay = i == 0 ? 0.25 : sqrt(Double(i)) * 0.5`

Comment: you just dont give up, do you? :) the sqrt is worse than log and the last one is useless. tried many values and modifiers. the problem is that it doesn't respect and include object.count into calculation

Comment: Haha, just throwing ideas :P Running through my simulator and looking at outputs. Nonetheless, I'm blindly searching for an algorithm to complete your goal haha. Ah well, all good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187194/discussion-between-anton-shevtsov-and-impression7vx).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the function below, which depends on the object count as you specified earlier and if the array will have more objects each animation will be executed with less delay but nonetheless first item's delay will be longer than latter:

```
for (i,object) in objects.enumerated() {
    object.animate(withDelay: ((1/((i+1)*0.5)) * 0.25) / objects.count)
}
```

There are a lot of parantheses but I hope it will increase readability, also I applied i+1 so you wont have division by zero problem for the first item.

With this formula I hope the delay will diminish gradually and smoothly when your array has large amount of objects.

**Note:**

- If you think delay is too much when there are not much elements in the array (which will lower the "objects.count" number. Try replacing `objects.count` with `(2 * objects.count)`
- Also if you think the reverse (delay is not much) when there are a lot of elements in the array (which will increase the "objects.count" number. Try replacing `objects.count` with `(objects.count / 2)`

Comment: thank you for your time, but your formula produces inconsistent results :( if i use original its ok for 1-3 objects. but if i use more than 10 it is super quick making delays like 0.001 etc. if i use objects.count / 2 or more it will crash. also the main thing is that i want for delay is to increase with the progress of index (i) not reduce

Comment: 7 objects delays are:
0.07142857142857142
0.03571428571428571
0.023809523809523808
0.017857142857142856
0.014285714285714287
0.011904761904761904
0.01020408163265306

and i wanted something like this 
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
etc

but for 3 objects i would love to see:
0
0.25
0.45